# Test for significant differences for data between 0 and 1

Tags: hypothesis-testing, quasi-likelihood

I have to test for significant differences between scenarios. Data consist of the length of a segment divided by the total length of the network. They are distributed between 0 (never equal to 0) and 1, with the length of the network changing. My data contains also many 1s. An example is:

| basin | scenario 1 | scenario 2 | scenario 3 | Network length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.00 | 0.11 | 0.5 | 15 |
| 2 | 0.95 | 0.7 | 0.13 | 1500 |

I tried a GLM with quasi-binomial family in R with model 'data ~ scenario' The summary is :

Coefficients:

|  | Estimate Std. | Error t | value | Pr(>t) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 2.91314 | 0.10747 | 27.107 | <2e-16 *** |
| scenario 1 | -0.05700 | 0.15008 | -0.380 | 0.704 |
| scenario 2 | -0.08756 | 0.14910 | -0.587 | 0.557 |
| scenario 3 | -0.10635 | 0.14851 | -0.716 | 0.474 |

------- cut ----------

(Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be 0.594791)

Null deviance: 3166.8  on 10539  degrees of freedom.

Residual deviance: 3165.0  on 10530  degrees of freedom

The test is never significant neither for scenarios nor for pairwise comparison (with means). Am I using the correct distribution for these data? Is it fully correct to use a GLM to test for significant differences among groups of data in a case like this?

Comment: What do you want to test?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion: You could investigate (test via simulation) based on the **Triangular Distribution**.

Not confident that you get anything useful here (as your data appears to be somewhat sparse), but a simulation exercise could provide insights on expected accuracy as your sample size increases. Results could also be compared (and/or combined) with other approaches.

Background: [Per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution), to quote:

> **Distribution of the absolute difference of two standard uniform variables**
>
> This distribution for a = 0, b = 1 and c = 0 is the distribution of X = |X1 − X2|, where X1, X2 are two independent random variables with standard uniform distribution.

The expected value is 1/3 and associated variance 1/18.

More research [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549672/intuition-for-triangular-distribution-as-difference-of-uniform-distributions) finds the following more precise commentary:

> Note that X − Y will only have a triangular distribution if b − a = d − c (that is, the joint support is a square interval), otherwise it will have a trapezoidal distribution.

Note: I am looking at the problem from the perspective that the data may consist inherently of samples taken from, say, a Uniform Distribution (hence, the non-traditional analysis). This may be representative of your data upon excluding your reported presence 'of many ones'.